# Provide a new token based on the refresh token without going to the client - JWT - Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, authorize

I have found many links but I didn't get the solution for my problem.

I am trying to implement the jwt refresh token in asp.net core.

For storing the refresh token, I have created the table. 
Based on the jwt suggestion, for SPA application, we should not expose refresh token to the client. https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

So I have planned like,

- On user login, create the access token and share to the client
- Create a refresh token for the access token and store it in the database and store it in HTTP only cookie
- When user access to the authorized controller and action, If access token expire, I want to generate new token based on refresh token.

But,
In many places, I have found like, user will send a request. If it is unauthorised, then user will request for the new access token with the stored refresh token (local storage or something else) and again call to the valid api request.

I don't want to that as mentioned in the last paragraph(is that right one?).

When user send a request, if it is invalid, I want to validate the token in the server side itself and need to provide new access token and proceed with the last api call.

Is there any solution for this implementation like interpreting the authorize and validate?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , it is dangerous to use/keep refresh token in SPA apps. Refresh token is powerful instrument , which is almost as powerful as the password itself . Store it in cookies or localStorage and both of these options are inherently insecure as they’re vulnerable to CSRF or XSS attacks against the client application . So i think it's better to just keep access token and do silent sign-in to renew it when access token expires.

So i don't think it's a good idea to return and use refresh token if client app is  SPA application even using Code + PKCE .

Comment: What does it mean silent sign-in? Do we need to keep user credentials in localstorage and do auto sign in? - meanwhile I have read in somewhere that If we enable httponly (asp.net core) for cookies, the attack will be avoided.

Comment: No , and you can click here for more details : https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-securely-implement-authentication-in-single-page-applications-670534da746f

Comment: You can store acces token in httponly and Secure flag  for cookie , and shold also protect your forms against CSRF attacks .But refresh token is not designed for SPA

Comment: Thank you. But if refresh token is not designed for SPA, what can we do on access token expire...